# How to cancel a background job in Azure functions triggered by message

Tags: .net, azure-functions, cancellation-token

Our system does an import of large files which is done by an Azure function. The flow is triggerd by an import endpoint which places a message on a queue that starts the background job.

Endpoint that triggers the function:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("dataset/{datasetId:int}/importFile")]
        [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
        [RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<FileImportResponse>> ImportFile(string sourceId, int datasetId, [FromForm] UploadRequest uploadRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var identPseudonym = User?.PidPseudonym();

            var fileImportResponse = await AddFileImport(sourceId, datasetId, uploadRequest, identPseudonym);

            await _importService.StartImportAsync(identPseudonym, datasetId, cancellationToken);

            var importCubeFileMessage = new ImportCubeFileMessage(identPseudonym, source.Id, datasetId);

            //Azure queueClient
            await _queueService.Enqueue(importCubeFileMessage);

            return Ok(fileImportResponse);
        }
```

The function trigger looks like this, simplified a bit for readability:

```
        [Function("FileImporterQueueTrigger")]
        public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("importfile", Connection = "ImportAccount")]
            ImportCubeFileMessage importCubeFileMessage, FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("FileImporter");
            logger.LogInformation($"Starting FileImporter (Queue trigger: {importFileMessage})");

            try
            {
                await _messageHandler.Start(importFileMessage);
                logger.LogInformation("Finished FileImporter");
            }
            catch (IgnoreMessageHandlerException ex)
            {
                logger.LogWarning(ex, "FileImporter Failed, should be ignored without notification");
            }
        }
```

And the `_messageHandler.Start(importFileMessage)` method looks something like this, also simplified:

```
        protected override async Task Start(ImportFileMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            //Find dataset to import
            var dataset = await dbContext.Dataset.Where(dataset =>
                    dataset.Id == message.DatasetId && dataset.FileImport.Any(
                        fi => fi.ImportStatus == FileImportStatus.Idle && fi.ImportTypeId == (int)FileImportTypeEnum.Csv))
                .Include(include => include.FileImport!)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

            await Import(dataset, sourceContext, cancellationToken);
        }
```

The message handler accepts a cancellation token, but none is sent from the function trigger yet, because I'm not sure where that token would come from.

The import endpoint is triggered from a frontend GUI and the active import job should also be able to be cancelled from the frontend. Now I'm assuming that I can't cancel through the same endpoint that I start the import from, since when the import starts the scope of the endpoint request is finished and the cancellationToken is no longer usable. So my question is how can I pass a cancellationToken from the frontend to the active import background job? I was thinking I could create a new endpoint which triggers a cancellation, but how would I make sure that this cancellation would cancel the same job as was triggered?